# PowerPoint Progress Bar VBA on single slide

Tags: vba, powerpoint

i want create a vba macro in powerpoint for show a progress bar under the current slide only. The progress bar has to go 1 step for a time (ex: 1000msec). It's possible?
I've modified this code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284530/how-to-make-a-progress-bar-in-powerpoint-vba) but it doesn't work properly, because i can't draw a shape on the current slide.

```
On Error Resume Next
    With ActiveWindow.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide
          For x = 1 To length
          Set s = .Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, _
          0, ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideHeight - 12, _
          x * ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideWidth / length, 12)
          s.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(127, 0, 0)
          s.Name = "ProgBar"
          Threading.thread.sleep (1000)
          Next x:
    End With
```

Comment: You don't need to draw the shape ... the code does it for you.  But Threading.thread.sleep isn't VBA.  That may be why it's not working for you.  You'll want to be clearer about what's not working; quote any error messages you see and indicate what line they occur on.  In order to do that, you'll want to comment out the "on error resume next" line.

Answer (score 0):

Try This. [Source](http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00597_Add_a_-thermometer-_progress_bar_to_each_slide.htm)

Read this, and try to learn of that piece of code.

Source: PPTFAQ (Website)

Answer (score 0):

there are a couple lines of code or simple steps on the web (though, imho quite hard to find) and they cover the basics only.

I extended the progress dots from Edgar Loper quite a bit. Please check out the **free** - and **open source** (you can look at the code there) - version of my/a **PowerPoint Progress Indicator** at the following link.

The ZIP includes a PPT add in which adds a new ribbon to PowerPoint and **works on Windows and MAC, Office 2010 and up, 32bit and 64bit!**

It lets you create a nice progress bar with extra infomation (if you structure your presentation).

Link to the latest version:

Short URL: http://url.olaf-noehring.de/progressindicator

Full URL: http://www.datenbank-projekt.de/index.php/beispiele/progress-indicator-powerpoint-2010-2013-2016-32-and-64-bit-windows-and-mac-os

(and Adam Wilsons Github page: https://github.com/AdamWilsonLab/progress_indicators )

Olaf